# (Laravel 6.0) Route prefix web.php not redirecting properly

Tags: laravel

I've set up the following routes on my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});


Route::prefix('app')->group(function () {
    // Registration routes
    Route::get('registration/create', 'RegistrationController@create')->name('app-registration-form');
});


// Templates
Route::get('templates/ubold/{any}', 'UboldController@index');
```

Now I would expect that if I open the URL `https://test.dev/app/registration/create` the corresponding view gets loaded. But in my case I get a `404 Not Found`.

Strange is that the page loads successful if I call `https://test.dev/registration/create`

php artisan route:list returns:

```
|        | GET|HEAD | registration/create                    | app-registration-form          | App\Http\Controllers\RegistrationController@create            | web                                             |
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I could debug the issue?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to clear your routes by running `php artisan route:clear` and then try to see your routes list again.

Comment: @rkg Still the same result :-(

Comment: Why don't you redirect to the route name instead of redirecting to a url?

Comment: LOL. No worries. Sometimes it's just a simple human error and not really a code error. Cheers! Happy coding!